# Multiple time series plots using ggplot2 with each having unequal number of observations

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking for some help with multiple time series plot as per the following description.

I have a data frame with the following structure. Column isin is repeating and it has 5 unique values. For each isin, there are multiple rows of data consisting of t_week, MS and t_MS. Each isin has unequal number of rows. In another words, the data frame has 2 time series (t_week, MS) (t_week, t_MS) for each isin with unequal number of data points.

I would like to plot all the 5 isin time series (t_week, MS) on a single plot using ggplot2. I can plot multiple time series of equal length easily, but looking for help here doing it right "The R" way. Please help.

regards

K

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   95 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ isin  : chr  "IN0019960056" "IN0019960056" "IN0019960056" "IN0019960056" ...
 $ t_week: Date, format: "2006-01-09" "2006-01-16" ...
 $ MS    : num  0 0 0.01 0.86 0.54 0.23 1.55 0.07 0.29 0.79 ...
 $ t_MS  : num  0.14 0.14 0.14 0.75 0.35 0.31 0.63 0.28 0.54 0.52 ...
```

Comment: Please give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059).

Comment: And please show us the code you use right now to construct the plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canocial `ggplot2` way is the following:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = t_week, y = MS, color = isin)) + geom_line()
```

this wil construct a plot of `t_week` vs `MS`, with a differently colored line for each unique element in `isin`. It is no problem that the timeseries do not consist of the same number of rows, they don't even have to cover the same time range. An example:

```
df_part1 = data.frame(t_week = seq(1,5,length=100), MS = runif(100), isin = "A")
df_part2 = data.frame(t_week = seq(2,6,length=500), MS = runif(500) + 1, isin = "B")
df = rbind(df_part1, df_part2)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = t_week, y = MS, color = isin)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome @Paul. Thanks a bunch. I was trying all sort of combinations using ddply and melt leading to non-sensible plots. Didn't occur to me that ISINs can be treated as categorical variables and ggplot will do the trick finally. Once again thanks for excellent solution.

Comment: If this solves your problem, you can mark it as such by clicking the green tick mark to the left, right next to my answer.